Consulta SQL a XLS en distintas hojas
Estoy intentando exportar varias consulta SQL a XLS mediante spool. Quería saber si alguien ha conseguido meter cada consulta en una hoja distinta.
Lo que me gustaría es que la consulta de la tabla1 fuera a una hoja y la consulta de la tabla 2 a otro.
SET ECHO OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET PAGES 0
SET TERMOUT OFF
SET SERVEROUTPUT OFF
SET TRIMOUT ON
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
-- INICIO DE GRABACION DE DATOS
SET MARKUP HTML ON
SPOOL archivo.xls
SELECT * FROM TABLA1

SELECT * FROM TABLA2
--FIN DE GRABACION DE DATOS
SPOOL OFF;
SET MARKUP HTML OFF;
SET ECHO ON;

Un saludo y muchas gracias

spool genera archivos simples, generalmente en formato de texto, separados por coma o delimitados. Hay un paquete open source llamado as_xlsx con el que puedes realizar la exportación a archivos de excel, y con ese puedes poner contenido en distintas hojas en un mismo libro. Si abres la pregunta a otras opciones, no solo spool, con gusto puedo publicar un pequeño ejemplo.

Gracias, desconocía este paquete, me ha servido muchísimo. Muchas gracias

Excelente, lo publiqué como una respuesta con un pequeño ejemplo para que no quede aquí perdido en comentarios.

El comando spool no hace más que escribir la salida que produzcan los comandos enviados al motor en un archivo de texto (simple). El hecho de que le coloques extensión 'xls' no lo convierte en un archivo de excel (con ese formato).
Si quieres escribir los resultados a un archivo de excel, puedes valerte del paquete de código abierto as_xlsx.
Un ejemplo de su uso podría ser:
BEGIN
  as_xlsx.clear_workbook;
  as_xlsx.new_sheet('tabla1');
  as_xlsx.query2sheet('select * from tabla1', p_sheet => 1);
  as_xlsx.new_sheet('tabla2');
  as_xlsx.query2sheet('select * from tabla2', p_sheet => 2);
  as_xlsx.save('MiDirectorio', 'archivo.xlsx');
END;
/


Muchas gracias.
